# Three fragment within viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have this problem as you can see in the pictures below:

1) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/schermata20120512a09444.png/
2) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/schermata20120512a09444.png/

I have done one viewpager with three fragment , but when scroll, I see one of them, i would see two fragments.

my cose is:

public class FragmentProjetSwipePageActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

```
// derived from http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/


// list contains fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
List<Fragment> fragmentsV1 = new Vector<Fragment>();

// page adapter between fragment list and view pager
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
// view pager
private ViewPager mPager;


// activity data
public String p2text,p3text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // creating fragments and adding to list
    fragmentsV1.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Page1Fragment.class.getName()));
            fragmentsV1.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Page2Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragmentsV1.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Page3Fragment.class.getName()));



    // creating adapter and linking to view pager
    mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager1);
    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentsV1,this );
    mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);


    //Set a listener that will be invoked whenever the page changes or is incrementally scrolled.
```

}
    }

PagerAdapter.java

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
// fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
private List<Fragment> fragments;
FragmentManager fm;
private static int NUM_PAGER_VIEWS = 2;

Context contex;

// constructor
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager _fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(_fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
    fm=_fm;

}

// return access to fragment from position, required override
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

// number of fragments in list, required override
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return NUM_PAGER_VIEWS;
    //return this.fragments.size();

}
```

}

thanks

Comment: Do you realize that there is already a built in class by name `PagerAdapter`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

Comment: @Enigma "FragmentPagerAdapter" is an extension of PageAdapter

Comment: Well, I know that. In your case, it is the other way round. You're extending PagerAdapter from FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: @Enigma Sorry,I no understand , If i change the name of class "PagerAdapter" in "PageHandler" the result is the same..How do I  solve the problem as in picture above?

Comment: I need a viewpager with 2 view in activity but scroll one view a time, in total I have 3 view.

Comment: That's not possible with ViewPager. You should probably use ScrollView instead and add views to it and make it horizontally scrollable.

Comment: Check this out - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Comment: solution: HorizontalScrollView 

thanks all :)